# How to use this InputReader class to get the users input?( get the int input from keybroad)

Tags: java, input

[the sample of InputReader class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2l7y.png)

Comment: please copy paste the code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a Scanner-Object by calling `InputReader()`. Then you either call `readString()` or `readInt()` to read strings and ints respectively. In the `readString()` you return the input immediately, while in `readInt()` you store it in `theInt` variable. Afterwards you can perform some other actions. Lastly, you need to close the scanner by `reader.close()`. All that can be done at once:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
int theInt = reader.nextInt();
/*Or get strings*/
String inputStr = reader.nextLine(); 
//perform some actions with the input
reader.close();
```